# Django templates – specifying common template folder returns "[Errno 22] Invalid argument"

Tags: django, django-templates

Okay, so I tried having a folder with static template elements accessible by all apps with two css files and one html file.

In settings.py I went to `TEMPLATES` and added: `'DIRS': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files'),`, as seen [here](https://pastebin.com/DR0mw9T0) (I edited out confidential info therefrom).

My template fragment `topnav.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="w3.css">
        <title>EvoLang</title>
    </head>

<!-- Content will go here -->
<body>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="topnav">
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a href="#">Entrywords
        <li><a href="#">Sentences
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- / Navigation -->
</body>
```

Then, in previously working `index.html` in my app `biblio` looks like this:

```
{% extends "topnav.html" %} {# this enables using the top navigation bar #}
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

What I get while accessing that page is the following error: `[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\MyProject\\myproject\\:\\biblio\\index.html'`
I don't really get what is this `\\:\\` part here.

I am using Django 1.11.2 with Python 3.6.

Comment: Please show the entire `TEMPLATES` setting, and the compete settings. If you print/log the `TEMPLATES` in your settings file, what do you get?

Comment: As an aside `static_files` is an odd name for a templates directory. You shouldn't be storing templates and static files (images, css and js) in the same place

Comment: @Alasdair I provided a pastebin with further information as per request. Why is having templates in the static folder a bad idea? Enabling unwanted access to my code from the client side? Anyway, I just want a folder for common elements of all my sub-pages/apps.

Comment: If you configure your webserver to serve files in your static directory, then your raw, unrendered templates will be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DIRS` setting should be a list. You are missing the square brackets and the trailing comma. Try:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')],
```

Comment: Well, indeed—a stupid mistake, thanks. Now I have to figure out how to make Django use the CSS referenced in that extended html, because for some reason it's ignored.

Comment: Start with the [docs on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css), and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: I think I just referenced them in the wrong place, but thanks for the tip :)